# Vba-Excel loop delete last row of a table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to learn a bit of VBA. So I'm new to this.

I want a loop that goes from the second  sheet until the last one, and then deletes the last line of a table in single one of the sheet's.

Currently I have this code that I search in the web.

```
 Sub ApagaLoop()
'Apaga todas as linhas das tabelas, e percorre todas as folhas.
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long


    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = 7

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 2 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        Sheets(I).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows().Select
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

    Next I

End Sub
```

And I'm getting an error in:

```
Sheets(I).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing Wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably your `ActiveWorkbook` has less then `7` worksheets

so just change

```
WS_Count = 7
```

to

```
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

furthermore you can avoid `Select`/`Selection` and use a full `Range` reference, as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ApagaLoop()
    'Apaga todas as linhas das tabelas, e percorre todas as folhas.
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 2 To WS_Count

        ' deletes the last line of current worksheet
        Worksheets(I).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

    Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `For Each ws In Worksheets` to reference the worksheets and `.Find` to reference the last row on the worksheet regardless of what column it is in.

```
Sub ApagaLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Range
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Index <> 1 Then

            Set Target = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not Target Is Nothing Then
                If MsgBox("Do you want to delete " & Target.EntireRow.Address(External:=True), vbYesNo, "Delete Last Row") = vbYes Then
                    Target.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```